Electron App with WhatsApp Integration: Works in Development, Fails in Production Build
Electron App with WhatsApp Integration: Works in Development, Fails in Production Build
Background
I'm developing an Electron application that integrates with WhatsApp using the @whiskeysocket/baileys library. The app includes features like QR code generation for WhatsApp Web login, message receiving, and media handling. I'm also using the qr-code library for QR code generation.
Problem
The application works correctly during the development stage. However, when I build it into an executable (.exe), it stops functioning properly. Specifically, the WhatsApp integration features fail to work as expected.
Environment

Electron (version: "electron": "^22.3.27")
@whiskeysocket/baileys (version:  "@whiskeysockets/baileys": "^6.7.8")
qr-code (version: "qrcode": "^1.5.4")

Code
Here's a simplified version of my main process code:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { makeWASocket, useMultiFileAuthState } = require('@whiskeysocket/baileys');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');
const Datastore = require('nedb');

let mainWindow;
let whatsappClient;
const appName = process.env.APPNAME;
const appData = app.getPath('userData');
const dbPath = path.join(appData, appName, "databases", "whatsapp.db");
const mediaPath = path.join(appData, appName, "databases", "whatsapp_media");

let whatsappDB = new Datastore({ filename: dbPath, autoload: true });

async function createWhatsAppClient() {
    try {
        const authPath = path.join(appData, appName, "whatsapp_auth");
        const { state, saveCreds } = await useMultiFileAuthState(authPath);

        whatsappClient = makeWASocket({
            printQRInTerminal: true,
            auth: state,
            connectTimeoutMs: 60000,
            defaultQueryTimeoutMs: 60000,
        });

        whatsappClient.ev.on("connection.update", async (update) => {
            const { connection, lastDisconnect, qr } = update || {};
            if (qr) {
                const qrDataURL = await qrcode.toDataURL(qr);
                mainWindow.webContents.send('qr-code', qrDataURL);
            }
            if (connection === 'open') {
                mainWindow.webContents.send('whatsapp-ready');
            }
        });

        whatsappClient.ev.on('messages.upsert', async (m) => {
            // Message handling logic here
        });

        whatsappClient.ev.on("creds.update", saveCreds);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in createWhatsAppClient: ', error);
    }
}

// IPC handlers and other main process code...


And here's a part of my renderer process code:
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const qrContainer = document.getElementById('qr-container');
    const connectionStatus = document.getElementById('connection-status');
    const messageList = document.getElementById('message-list');

    ipcRenderer.on('qr-code', (event, qr) => {
        qrContainer.innerHTML = '';
        const qrImage = new Image();
        qrImage.src = qr;
        qrContainer.appendChild(qrImage);
        connectionStatus.textContent = 'Scan this QR code with WhatsApp';
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('whatsapp-ready', () => {
        qrContainer.innerHTML = '';
        connectionStatus.textContent = 'WhatsApp is connected!';
        loadMessages();
    });

    // Other event listeners and functions...
});

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I've Tried

Checked all file paths to ensure they're using app.getPath('userData').
Verified that all dependencies are correctly listed in package.json.
Added error logging to catch any uncaught exceptions.
Ensured the WhatsApp client is initialized when the app starts.

Question

What could be causing the WhatsApp integration to fail in the production build?
Are there any specific considerations for packaging an Electron app with WhatsApp integration?
How can I better debug this issue in the production environment?

